# Must a Spring bean represent a unique object?

Tags: java, spring

Can Spring bean be a reference to another bean? It doesn't seem to work:

```
<bean id="player1" class="some.package.Player" />
<bean id="player2" ref="player1" />
```

If this is possible, is it useful? So far, I was thinking that every bean must represent a unique object, but some idea came to my head: what if I had a Singleton class called e.g. Sun with a "public static Sun getInstance()" method and I would make two beans being the same object?

```
<bean id="sun1" class="some.package.Sun" factory-method="getInstance" />
<bean id="sun2" class="some.package.Sun" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515367/static-factory-method-spring (not a 100% duplicate)

Comment: This is called aliasing.  check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ and search for alias

Comment: related: [Is spring default scope singleton or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31629993/217324)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the below

> `<bean id="player1" class="some.package.Player" />`
>
> `<bean id="player2" ref="player1" />`

I think you want to refer same bean with two or more names. If so, you can have comma separated list or ids as (alias concept)

`<bean id="player1, player2" class="some.package.Player" />`

Now you can refer the bean with either player1 or player2.

Similarly,

> `<bean id="sun1" class="some.package.Sun" factory-method="getInstance" />`
> `<bean id="sun2" class="some.package.Sun" factory-method="getInstance" />`

can be replaced with

`<bean id="sun1, sun2" class="some.package.Sun" factory-method="getInstance" />`

and this allows you to refer the same bean with two different ids.

And to understand when aliasing is useful, quoting from https://vladmihalcea.com/why-i-like-spring-bean-aliasing/,

> Bean aliasing allows us to override already configured beans and to
> substitute them with a different object definition. This is most
> useful when the bean definitions are inherited from an external
> resource, which is out of our control.

Comment: Does not answer the question, is that true: sun1.getInstance().hashCode() == sun2.getInstance().hashCode() ? I think it will refer to the same object as design pattern singleton in Java is created on class loader level.

Comment: @agilob Assuming the `getInstance()` is singleton implementation, yes hashCode will be same and both refer to same object.

Comment: It has to be the same because class is `public static class` <- I assume that what class implementation would be if author provided it.

Comment: `public static class` has nothing to do with how many instances can be created. Also `public static class` will  only work for inner beans and not top level beans.

Answer (score 0):

Beans are generally singletonic, so they represent one object *per context*. Standard singleton design pattern in java creates one object *per class loader*. I think in your case you will re-create one object twice, once with Spring beans, and once with own class loader executed implementation. So both suns will be the same when you compare their hash codes via `.getInstance().hashCode()`.